# jQuery scrolling using a draggable div

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm making a jQuery plugin that creates a scrollable div. You are able to scroll up and down using a div on the right hand side. The problem is that my draggable div seems to be quite juddery when moving it.

A full example of what I'm trying is here: http://jsfiddle.net/j8Hqq/1/

I think the offending code will be in here:

```
.mousemove(function(e) {
    if(being_dragged) {
        scroller_y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;

        if(scroller_y < 0)
            scroller_y = 0;
        else if(scroller_y > $this.height() - $(this).height())
            scroller_y = $this.height() - $(this).height();
    }

    $(this).css({
        top: scroller_y
    });

    $('#custom-scroll-children').scrollTop(scroller_y);
});
```

I was thinking about implementing jQuery-ui.draggable into it, but didn't want a large library attached to the plugin.

Thanks,

Comment: have you tried jScrollPane? http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).offset().top;` in mousemove receives wildy differing values, which is why it is as jerky as it is. I got smoother results by putting `topOffset = $(this).offset().top;` into the mousedown function, then using `scroller_y = e.pageY - topOffset;` in mousemove.

There are still issues (scrolling stops when the mouse leaves the scroll area, quick mouse movements will stop the scrolling) though.

Have you looked at http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ ? It's a jQuery plugin that pretty much does what you ae trying to achieve here.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was able to make it smoother by doing this. I'll carry on doing what I'm doing, but thanks for pointing out jScrollPane (and @Andy), I know I have something to fall back on if I fail!

Answer (score 0):

.css function make the draggable div juddery, you can try function "animate".